# React Native Debug JS Remotely Error window.deltaUrlToBlobUrl is not a function

Tags: react-native

I am trying to to debug the react native app, If I don't try to debug JS remotely then everything is fine, but when I try to debug JS remotely I do get this error.

[image]

Comment: Can you should us the code for `getBlobUrl`? You're probably referencing `this` which isn't the context you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed chrome CORS extension and enabled the CORS then it worked, Even If I open chrome with disable security manually then also it didn't worked for me until I install the extension.

Comment: seems like an awful hack, but i'm ok with it, thanks for this tip! helpful in a lot of other site debugging efforts i'm sure

Comment: could you add link of that extension their are tons of them

Answer (score 196):

I had this error too. The reason for me was the opened debugger tab in chrome from previous session. So when I closed it everything works fine now :)

Comment: This seems to be the true origin of this issue.

Comment: can confirm this solution is working fine for me! thanks

Comment: Perfect! Had to restart the Metro Bundler too

Comment: It was perfect!!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works in my case. Why doesn't the author accept this answer?

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm that - it's fixed for me when I empty cache and hard reload from chrome browser's reload the page button. 

Thanks a lot @ВладиславМихайленко :)

Comment: Close old tab AND then restart the emulator did it for me. Thanks

Comment: npm start --reset-cache and Also had to close current debugger and reload the device.
Your solution is the best one. Thanks!

Comment: Still works in 2020 - only had to close the debugger tab and then it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

try to change your URL of Chrome from http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ to http://192.168.XXXX.XXXX.xip.io:8081/debugger-ui/

source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17618

Comment: For me the solution didn't worked, I installed chrome CORS extension and enabled the CORS then it worked, Even If I open chrome with disable security manually then also it didn't worked for me until I install the extension. @Chotala thanks for your reply.

Comment: bare in mind that the IP address should be the one of your host (machine where you are running the node server), not the one of your client (mobile phone/ emulator)

Answer (score 7):

I had same error, I just closed the browser and refreshed my simulator. It may open the browser window again with debugging window. But it takes care of the error. If not I suggest terminating your simulator and running the build commands again.

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved by restarting JS debugging and closing existing debugger.

- Close Chrome debugger session

On iOS, do:

- `CMD + CTRL + Z`
- Press `Stop Remote JS Debugging`
- `CMD + CTRL + Z` Again
- `enable Remote JS Debugging`

Almost the same on Android, but the difference is the keyboard command it is `CMD + M` on Mac or `CTRL+M` on Windows devices.

Answer (score 3):

Close emulator.

Close node console which get opened after executing command react-native run-android.

Start emulator again.

Run project again.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

i just cleared my browser cache and my app cache and its working now
this error appears when you have

Comment: the end of your post is missing

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Found a better, less hacky solution. It seems when I upgraded Expo client on windows, it changed my default 'host'. Click the cog and change 'host' to 'LAN' to avoid CORS[image]