# not able to connect to React native debugger. M getting this error

Tags: react-native

```
deltaUrlToBlobUrl.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at deltaUrlToBlobUrl (deltaUrlToBlobUrl.js:30)
deltaUrlToBlobUrl @ deltaUrlToBlobUrl.js:30
async function (async)
ws.onmessage @ (index):182
deltaUrlToBlobUrl.js:29 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false with MIME type application/javascript. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in this answer, change your address bar direction in your browser, to point localhost:8081 (change the port if you are using something different). In my case I don't know why, instead of opening `localhost:88081/debugger-ui` it was opening `<my-ip-address>:8081/debugger-ui`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49365319/2128008